# Simple views handler to compute math expression.

Tags: views

In Views, I would like to expose a fake field that is just an elementary mathematical expression of other fields of the table (let's say, for example, field1+field2).

I expose the field in hook_vies_data via some

```
  $data['my_table']['fake_field'] = array(
   'field' => array(
     'handler' => 'views_handler_my_handler',
  );
```

Which function of the handler shall I define? And how do I get in the handler the two values of field1 and field2?

Alternatively, where do I found the documentation of what I am looking for?

Comment: how did you fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating own handler you should use already existent `Global: math expression` that allows you using of tokens to calculate everything you want.

Comment: The question was a bit simplified. The math expression I need is really more complicated, and can't be computed with the `Global: math expression handler.` I would just like to know where I find the documentation to write such a handler.

Comment: I never see normal documentation about handlers.
Just this one http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_handlers/7

Answer (score 0):

I've found this post that shows you how to create your custom views field handler for SQL expressions:

http://tech-tamer.com/drupal-7-using-sql-expressions-in-views-3/

For my needs it's enough, but if you need complex data maipulation in PHP I think it's also a good point to start to work with.

But you need to create your custom filter and sort handlers to allow it working with expressions:

```
[...]
'filter' => array(
  'handler' => 'NumericExpressionFilterHandler',
  'allow empty' => TRUE,
),
'sort' => array(
  'handler' => 'NumericExpressionSortHandler',
),
[...]
```

NumericExpressionFilterHandler.php:

```
class NumericExpressionFilterHandler extends views_handler_filter_numeric {
  function op_simple($field) {
    $placeholder = $this->placeholder();

    $this->query->add_having_expression($this->options['group'],
      str_replace('.', '_', $field) . " $this->operator $placeholder",
      array($placeholder => $this->value['value']));
  }

  /**
   * For simplicity limited to simple operations.
   * @return array
   */
  public function operators() {
    $op = parent::operators();

    foreach ($op as $i => $operation) {
      if ($operation['method'] != 'op_simple') {
        unset($op[$i]);
      }
    }

    return $op;
  }

}
```

NumericExpressionSortHandler.php

```
class NumericExpressionSortHandler extends views_handler_sort {
  /**
   * Called to add the sort to a query.
   */
  function query() {
    $this->ensure_my_table();
    // Add the field.
    $this->query->add_orderby(NULL, NULL, $this->options['order'], $this->table_alias . '_' . $this->real_field);
  }

}
```

Regards.

Comment: Please include a relevant quote of that hyperlink in your answer here. That will avoid your answer is perceived as a link-only answer (which may get deleted via moderation).